# How to start imacros from html or php?

Tags: imacros

I'd like to call imacros files from web pages to start automatically after button click or something. I have followed the imacros docs but i got confused.
Is there any method to do that?

thanks

Comment: Can you add what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have tried this sample at http://wiki.imacros.net/PHP on my Apache localhost but it gave this error message " Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `imacros': Invalid syntax ' in J:\AppServ\www\sample.php:2 Stack trace: #0 J:\AppServ\www\sample.php(2): com->com('imacros') #1 {main} thrown in J:\AppServ\www\sample.php on line 2".

Comment: What browser for 'iMacros' do you use? I know definitely that for Firefox extension you can do what you need (i.e. to run from html).

Comment: Yes iam using Firefox extension. is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple code did the job in new iMacros version.
imacros://run/?m=macrofile.iim

for example

```html
<a href="imacros://run/?m=macrofile.iim">Run macro</a>
```